# Billing phone calculator

Tags: kotlin

I have the code for my phone bill calculator. It charges users 0.25 for every minute they were over the plan and 15% tax on the subtotal. Now I have to separate the methods to calculate the tax, overage fees, and final total by printing the itemized bill. Can you help me to separate the methods?

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Enter the Total Minutes of Calls Made this Month: ")
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val numberOfMinutes = scan.nextInt()

    var excessMinutes = numberOfMinutes - 60
    if (excessMinutes < 0) {
        excessMinutes = 0
    }
    val bill = 10 + excessMinutes * 0.25
    val taxedBill = bill * 1.15

    println("\nTelephone Bill this Month = $taxedBill")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's already a pretty short function, so I'm guessing refactoring it like that is a homework exercise! You need to work out how to break the steps down into separate tasks that return a result.

Try replacing this:

```
var excessMinutes = numberOfMinutes - 60
if (excessMinutes < 0) {
    excessMinutes = 0
}
```

with this:

```
val excessMinutes = someFunction()
```

That's a `val` now, so you can't change it once you get the result. `someFunction` needs to do *all* the calculation, and return a result. What needs to go in that function? What type of value does it need to return? Do you need to pass any values *into* that function as parameters, so it can use them in the calculation?

Once you work that out, the rest should be pretty straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor it like that

```
import java.util.* 

fun main() {
    print("Enter the Minutes of Calls Made this Month: ") 
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val numberOfMinutes = scan.nextInt()
    var excessMinutes = numberOfMinutes - 60 
    if (excessMinutes < 0) {
        excessMinutes = 0
    }
    val bill = 10 + excessMinutes * 0.25
    val fees = excessMinutes * 0.25
    val taxedBill = bill * 1.15
    val tax = taxedBill - bill
        
    println("\nOverage fees = $fees")
    println("\nTax = $tax")
    println("\nFinal total = $taxedBill")
}
```